# Which is better for a .NET developer: Eclipse or MonoDroid?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am learning Android development on Eclipse. As I am a .NET developer, I am not very comfortable with either the Eclipse environment or the Android libraries. Here I have two options: I can go with Eclipse or MonoDroid for Visual Studio. Which one should be better for me?

Comment: As far I know, you need to learn Java to develop for Android with Eclipse. By the way, it's a great opportunity to learn something new!

Comment: Mono for android isn't free so jvm is sorta better way to start but emerge full assortment of jvm languages which supports android development. Clojure etc ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a .Net Developer as well. And with the Monodevelop work I did. It was very difficult to get things to sync up correctly. the Eclipse development ended up being the way to go. Until they work all the kinks out of the Monodevelop debugger then eclipse is the way to go.

If you are going to pay for the license for monodevelop then that may be the way to go as the debugging on the Device is supposed to be better, but for my time and effort and the lack of good information or a trial of the MonoDevelop license to deploy on the devices it was a ditch effort. I decided to go with the Eclipse. Not to mention that Eclipse works the same on any platform as long as you can set it up.

It will be real nice when they get the monodevelop stuff working without a hitch. The ease of coding in visual studio is second to none. But like Tim says. Theres loads of stuff showing you what to do in Java. Not nearly as much in C#

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a little too subjective for here so you may get closed as these type of questions often start flame wars.

But for me (also mostly a .NET dev) I find that right now today, Eclipse is still the better choice for the simple reason that there are far more examples and resources available for it, as a newb I need all the help I can get, and if I am using the mainstream tool then I feel I am better placed.

My advise, once you get past Hello World and a couple other samples, try em all and see what fits for you.